# How to constrain a moving circle in a larger circle

Tags: ios, algorithm, geometry

I am working on a problem in iOS that involves a moving circle (circle a of radius r) within a larger static circle (circle b of radius t). t > r.

Circle a can move anywhere within circle b, but stops as soon as it touches circle b. I'm implementing the rendering of the circle by adding x and y offsets to the starting center point of circle a, and redrawing it each time. The calculations for the offsets are being made using some gravity and friction coefficient values. I understand that I have to subtract some value from the offsets if circle a goes out of circle b. How do I calculate the offsets in a way that circle a is constrained within circle b?

I can achieve the same when constrained in a rectangle, but scratching my head making the calculations for constraining it in a circle.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a lot easier if you change where the calculation is. Instead of trying to calculate whether the circumference of the inner circle goes outside the outer circle you can reduce this to look at the centres.

If you have an outer circle of radius `R` and an inner circle of radius `R'` then, because they are circles we can say that if the inner circle centre is greater than `(R - R')` away from the centre it will be outside the outer circle.

So, if the centre of the outer circle is at `(0,0)` then we just need to calculate the Pythagorean distance of the centre of the inner circle.

If the coordinates of the centre of the inner circle is `(x,y)` then we can do the calculation…

```
if x*x + y*y > (R - R') * (R - R') {
  // inner circle is outside outer circle
}
```

If the outer circle centre is not at (0,0) then you just have to use `dx` and `dy` in the calculation where `dx = outer circle centre x - inner circle centre x` and same for `dy`.

Comment: Thanks for the info Fogmeister. I'm still a bit confused. How do I calculate the x,y coordinates of the center of the inner circle when it's just touching the outer circle? In this case the center of both the circles is not (0, 0) to start with.

if x*x + y*y > (R - R') * (R - R') {
  // inner circle is outside outer circle
//how would I calculate the x, y values in a way that the inner circle is constrained.
}

Comment: How are you positioning the circle in the first place. When you draw the circle you will be giving it a position. Either a centre position and a radius or a bounding square. Use that to get the centre position of the circle.

Comment: The center for both circles is the canvas (or screen) (x=screen.width/2, y=screen.width/2). The outer circle stays static while the inner circle moves.

Comment: I also set the initial xOffset and yOffset to 0, and update them as required. When I redraw, I make the new calculations as newX = centerX + xOffset and newY = centerY + yOffset.

Comment: Ok, so there’s your x and y.

Comment: Now, if the inner circle is about to go outside the outer circle, how do I adjust xOffset and yOffset? if (distanceBetweenCircles > outerCircleRadius - innercircleRadius) { xOffset -= ? , yOffset -= ?}

Comment: Oh, well your question just said that when it gets to the outside of the circle it stops moving. You didn’t mention anything else about other movement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248303/discussion-between-peace4theapes-and-fogmeister).